# jQuery Xpath selector to select an element which id contains 'sometext'

Tags: asp.net, jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors, contains

I have a listbox element in aspx page which id is attributesList.

I want to select this element to track its change event, but i cant directly select its id because asp.net changes its id on runtime.

its id, attributesList changes into ctl00_adminPlaceHolder_attributesList.

so what i want to do is to use a "contains" xpath expression to select the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to instead use the ["End with" attribute selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue) like so:

```
$("*[id$='attributesList']")
```