# Using a regular expression to find a link with a certain anchor when using mechanize

Tags: ruby, regex, mechanize

I'm trying to use the Mechanize link_with(:href => 'anchor here') in order to find pages that have links with a certain string in the href. For example I want it so that I can spit out into a text file all sites that have a link where the anchor contains "index.php?user"

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks all for your answers, I ended up going with page.link_with(:href => /(.*)?user$/)

Comment: thanks for this.. i was looking for a way to feed regex into mechanize.. great!

Answer (score 1):

```
urls = ['http://www.google.com/','http://www.foo.com/','http://www.bar.com/']

File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |out|
  urls.each do |url|
    out << url if agent.get(url).link_with(:href => /index.php\?user/)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into XPath selectors:

[jQuery Xpath selector to select an element which id contains 'sometext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075760/jquery-xpath-selector-to-select-an-element-which-id-contains-sometext)

An example on how to use XPath with mechanize can be found here:

[extract single string from HTML using Ruby/Mechanize (and Nokogiri)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114695/extract-single-string-from-html-using-ruby-mechanize-and-nokogiri)